# How to store hd wallet seed in production server

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, wallet-security

I've developed a cryptocurrency payment gateway, which is a web application that generates new addresses for users, I've developed a HD wallet as a hot wallet for my application, and all addresses for different coins generated from a master key(seed), so this seed is a crucial part of my application,  whats a most secure way of storing this seed in production server except 2way encryption?